BasicTextField2: Placeholder with Floating Label Behavior jetpack compose
I'm trying to achieve a floating label effect with BasicTextField2 in Jetpack Compose. My goal is to have a placeholder that:
Is initially displayed inside the text field when empty.
Transitions to a smaller label above the text field when the user starts typing.
This should mimic the behavior of the standard TextField component with a label.
Here's my current BasicTextField2 code:
@Composable
fun MyTextField() {
    var text by remember { TextFieldState("") }

    BasicTextField2(
            state = registerState.email.text,
            lineLimits = TextFieldLineLimits.SingleLine,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(1.dp, Color(0xFFF7E6E9), RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        )
}

How can I implement this floating placeholder/label effect within BasicTextField2?
Expected Output

Without focus Input field


With focus Input field




You can set value of BasicTextField2's decorator to TextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox for achieving this behaviour.

BasicTextField2 was in development and did not have a stable API. It's now migrated to another overload of BasicTextField, and its decorator parameter is now required to be a TextFieldDecorator, so unfortunately the approach mentioned by @AdnanHabib no longer works

@pontiac_ventura Interesting, can you share the changelog? By the way, BasicTextField2 also requires TextFieldDecorator, which is provided by TextFieldDefaults.

BasicTextField2 was a temporary solution. As of Compose Foundation 1.7.0-alpha04 it's no longer available and its been renamed to BasicTextField.
The new BasicTextField has a decorationBox, where you can wrap the "core input" with a layout of your liking.
You can look at M3 library's source for an example, since the TextField still takes in a placeholder parameter.
